# How can I check if each record of a database has a similar record for all columns except one?

Tags: sql

I have a table with records as below:

[image]

I need to verify that for each combination of Number, Name, if the Code is null then there is another record with same Number, Name which has Code as 1. There can be a record with Code 1 but no corresponding Code null.

I tried

```
select t1.name,t1.number,t1.code, t2.code 
from 
   (select distinct name,number,code from dummy 
    where code is null) t1, 
   (select distinct name,number,code  from dummy 
    where code is not null) t2 
where t1.name=t2.name and t1.number=t2.number
```

My idea was to check if for every null in t1.code there is a 1 in t2.code. But I see repetitions in my result. Can anyone please help?

Comment: So, what is the expected result?

Comment: Your inner select doesnt have `FROM`

Comment: as Giorgos say, what is your expected result.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to verify and make sure there are none (or find the ones which don't have a code = 1) then you can simply do this:

```
select number, name from table where code is NULL
minus
select number, name from table where code = 1
```

Comment: Depending on your rdbms, `MINUS` might not work. Apparently `EXCEPT DISTINCT` is equivalent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#EXCEPT_operator), but that might not work in your database either.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    T1.number,
    T1.name
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    T1.code IS NULL AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM My_Table T2
        WHERE
            T2.number = T1.number AND
            T2.name = T1.name AND
            T2.code = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using group-by, switch-case and sum.

The following seems to work in SQL-Server-Express :

Query :

```
select num, name, SUM(case code when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) valid_row_count 
from SO_37195434  group by num,name;
```

Output:

```
num name    valid_row_count
1   A           1
2   b           1
2   c           1
```

Update :

Using `sum(isnull(code,0))` works too!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, t2.code from t t1
left outer join t t2 on t1.number = t2.number and t1.name = t2.name and t2.code = 1
where t1.code is null and t2.number is null;
```

This will give you the rows where `t1.code` is null, but there is no corresponding `t2.code` with value 1.